# Warning: mysql_query(): 25 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/..../classes/class_core.php on line 60

Tags: php, mysql

I have gone through all the related answers.

when I'm using http://sitename this doesn't occur, but when I use https://sitename this error occurs

> Warning: mysql_query(): 25 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in
>   /home/.../classes/class_core.php
>   on line 60

here's the code

```
function &execute_query($buffered = true, &$link) {
    $this->connection_recent = &$link;

    $this->querycount++;
//line 60 is below
    if ($queryresult = $this->functions[($buffered ? "query" : "query_unbuffered")]($this->sql, $link)) {
        $this->sql = "";
        return $queryresult;
    }

    $this->sql = "";
}
```

I'm using hostgator business account.

Comment: Looks SSL issue. Have you contact hostgator about this?

Comment: Yes @Jack They asked me to contact a developer or post on a site like stackoverflow :)

Comment: Ok. Check in phpinfo. HTTPS is enabled or not

Comment: Refer to http://forums.hostgator.com/php-not-detecting-shared-ssl-t44870.html

Answer (score 1):

I got through by changing

```
$this->connection_recent = &$link;
```

into

```
$this->connection_recent = $this->connection_master;
```

Hope this helps someone someday :)